# Hyperledger error 500 on REST API : ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer, endorsed

I followed this tutorial : (https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org) to deploy a multi-organization network. And when I try to POST a transaction from my REST API, I have the following error :

**"Error trying invoke business network. Error: Peer localhost:7051 has rejected transaction 'e12bc56bf4c0af54f7909a976da0c1342ec08a4872bff611eff392635b01cfb1' with code ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE"**

I do have the same error if I try to POST a transaction from command line.

My endorsement policy is the following :

```
{
"identities": [
    {
        "role": {
            "name": "member",
            "mspId": "Org1MSP"
        }
    },
    {
        "role": {
            "name": "member",
            "mspId": "Org2MSP"
        }
    }
],
"policy": {
    "2-of": [
        {
            "signed-by": 0
        },
        {
            "signed-by": 1
        }
    ]
 }
}
```

I know that this means that both organizations have to agree with each transaction but I don't know how am I suppose to make the organizations agree concretely. Does anyone know how to deal with this issue ?

NB : If I try to create an asset or a participant from the REST API it works.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can successfully create an Asset with a POST request, then you are executing a *system transaction* called **AddAsset** - and the endorsement works OK.

I would think that in your transaction you have a field that is a Timestamp or Random number or other generated field that is calculated separately on each peer giving a different answer and therefore failing endorsement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, I do have a Timestamp field and a transactionId field. 
I delete this two fields in the JSON used to do my POST request (if I don't I will get another error).
Do you think that it is the problem ? If yes, what should I do to avoid it ?

Comment: It is a feature of the REST server that it shows the timestamp and transactionid in the example JSON.  You must not specify these 2 fields in the POST - Composer generates them for you.  After you have succeeded POSTing a transaction, you can GET it and you will see the 2 fields.

Comment: Actually I had a random field. And it was indeed the problem ! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks,  for my case I was using the current time as the id of the asset, so each of the  peer had a different id and therefore the transaction couldn't be endorsed.